# NPAPI plugin with Web Worker Thread

Tags: npapi, web-worker

I am aware of accessing NPAPI plugin from Javascript and I was able to implement the communication between the two.

I wanted to know if it is possible to access the APIs exposed by the NPAPI plugin from the Web Worked Thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to an NPAPI plugin from a web worker thread is exactly the same as accessing any other DOM element from a web sorker thread.  From [the mozilla documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers):

```
There's no access to non-thread safe components or the DOM and you have to pass specific data in and out of a thread through serialized objects.
```

NPAPI is not aware of web workers, thus it is non-thread safe.  In fact, all calls in an NPAPI plugin that talk to javascript have to be made on the main thread; all NPN_ functions (with a few specific exceptions) must only be called on the main thread.  NPAPI is not thread-aware.

***Summary***: No, you can't.